# Homework: Algorithm to determine the two most popular items in a shopping cart

Tags: algorithm, if-statement, logic

I'm trying to determine the two most popular items in a user's shopping cart.

Each time the user adds or removes an item to/from the cart a function `updatePopularity(Item item)` is called which is passed a single argument referencing the object that was updated. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
  private void updatePopularity(InventoryItem item)
  {
    InventoryItem tempItem;

    if (mostPopular == null)
    {
      if (item.count > 0)
      {
        mostPopular = item;
        mostPopularLabel.setText(MOST_POPULAR + " " + item.name);
      }
    }
    else if (nextPopular == null)
    {
      if (mostPopular.name != item.name && item.count > 0)
      {
        nextPopular = item;
        nextPopularLabel.setText(NEXT_POPULAR + " " + item.name);
      }
    }
    else if (mostPopular.count < item.count)
    {
      tempItem = mostPopular;
      mostPopular = item;
      mostPopularLabel.setText(MOST_POPULAR + " " + item.name);

      nextPopular = tempItem;
      nextPopularLabel.setText(NEXT_POPULAR + " " + nextPopular.name);
    }
    else if (nextPopular.count < item.count)
    {
      nextPopular = item;
      nextPopularLabel.setText(NEXT_POPULAR + " " + nextPopular.name);
    }
    else if (mostPopular.count == 0)
    {
    }
   }
```

I'm getting all fumbled in the logic though because there are so many possible scenarios that can play out.

The end result should be:

- At any given moment the two items with the highest quantities in the shopping cart should appear as the most popular.
- If the second most popular ends up with a greater quantity, the two items should swap positions for most and next-most popular.
- As items are removed from the cart, popularity should also be updated.

Finally, if there is only one popular item because of cart updates, I should reflect that.

Can anyone help me with how to go about logically mapping out the possibilities?

I'm currently taking a Discrete Mathematics class, but I'm not far enough in to attempt solving this on paper yet. I'm not asking for the code to be written out for me, but just some guidance into how one works through the logic without a mess of `if` statements that get super confusing.

Comment: [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: Keep your logic clean or you will end up with bugs: use the appropriate data structures.  1. Sort by popularity 2. Update InventoryItem by popularity

Comment: @kfmfe04 I should probably mention that even though it's a shopping cart, I'm not working with a database. I could continuously sort the array, but if two items are tied, I don't want the most popular one to get swapped to second most popular and vice versa. I guess I could include some checks to make sure that doesn't happen, but I'm thinking my approach is wrong.

Comment: You can sort it in Java or whatever language you chose to use above - don't need a database to sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation I ended up using is not efficient but it works...

Each time an item is is added or removed from the cart, the inventory is scanned finding the first two occurrences of the most and second most popular items. Then, those items are compared to the current holders of most and second most popular. The tricky part was with the logic because if an item took first place, then the current item in first needs to get pushed to second. However, and if an item that was currently second got bumped to first, then the first item to have been tied for second needed to become second. I was trying to map out the logic on paper, but I just don't have the skills or knowledge to do that. I end up confusing myself. :)